# How to specify image in FFmpeg command

Tags: ios, swift, ffmpeg

I was able to successfully compile & import `FFmpeg` into my existing iOS app. However now I would like to run the following commands. Can anyone tell me, how to pass image name in `FFmpeg` command, I would like to form command in iOS swift.

I have an example in android:

String command = `“ -i beach.jpg output.jpg“`

If I mention image name `“beach.jpg”`, after adding it to my project,  in logs,

> error “No such file or directory”

Then I have created format

```
var resourceFolder = Bundle.main.resourcePath

var image1 = URL(fileURLWithPath: resourceFolder ?? "").appendingPathComponent("beach.jpeg").absoluteString
```

> Not supported

```
let imag = UIImage(named: "beach")
```

> Not supported

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got the answer ,  we have to give path of image there.

Ex:

```
 let resourceFolder = Bundle.main.resourcePath

 let input = URL(fileURLWithPath: resourceFolder ?? "").appendingPathComponent("pyramid.jpg").absoluteString

let out = "/Users/appleapple/Desktop/test/output1.jpg" 

let command = "-i \(image1) \(out)"

let test =  MobileFFmpeg.execute(command)
```